# Angular 2 ngModelChange old value

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-forms

Can someone please tell me what is the best practice for comparing ngModel old and new value?

In angular 1:

```
$scope.$watch('someProperty', funciton(oldVal, newVal){
    // code goes here
})
```

I am asking this because `(ngModelChange)` never brings me the `oldVal` , only the `newVal`.

In my case, I am using ngModel in a `<select>` tag and compare the old selection with the new one:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="current" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let item of myArray" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might work

```ts
(ngModelChange)="onModelChange(oldVal, $event); oldVal = $event;"
```

or

```ts
(ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
```

```ts
oldValue:string;
onModelChange(event) {
  if(this.oldValue != event) {
    ...
  }
  this.oldValue = event;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the oldVal param is undefined. I am using this comparation in a <select> tag (please look at my edited post)

Comment: Just declare a variable with this name in the components class. I added it to my code (in the 2nd example)

Comment: Ok, i get it now. but this solution seems to be very manually, are you sure that is the best practice? there is nothing delivered by angular 2 for getting the oldVal?

Comment: No, Angular only provides `$event` or if you use `[ngModel]="myValue"` updates the `myValue` property with the new value. If you use `[myProp]="someValue"` binding to an `@Input() myProp;`, then when the binding is updated `ngOnChanges(changes)`, `changes` contains the old value as well, but that doesn't apply to your situation, it is only for binding from parent to child.

Comment: In my case, select value is already set, so the value of `this.oldValue` is `undefined`, because the onModelChange would be run for the first time. Is there a workaround for this as well?

Answer (score 16):

Just for the future

we need to observe that [(ngModel)]="hero.name" is just a short-cut that can be de-sugared to: [ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event".

So if we de-sugar code we would end up with:

`<select (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()" [ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event">`

or

`<[ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event" select (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()">`

If you inspect the above code you will notice that we end up with 2 ngModelChange events and those need to be executed in some order.

Summing up: **If you place ngModelChange before ngModel, you get the $event as the new value, but your model object still holds previous value.**
If you place it after ngModel, the model will already have the new value.

[SOURCE](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234)

Sample stack blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zlhwex

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that these would literally fire sequentially based on their position in the template. A great help. Here's hoping they don't standardize the execution order for this at a later time...

Answer (score 9):

Example with input field...

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">{{value}}
    <input [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="old=value" (ngModelchange)="doSomething(old, value)">
</div>

doSomething(oldVal, newVal) {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: I am using this comparation in a <select> tag (see my edited post). i guess (focus) is not relevant anymore. can you please write an example with a select tag?