# (change) vs (ngModelChange) in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodelchange

Angular 1 does not accept `onchange()` event, it's only accepts `ng-change()` event.

Angular 2, on the other hand, accepts both `(change)` and `(ngModelChange)` events, which both seems to be doing the same thing.

What's the difference?

which one is best for performance?

**ngModelChange**:

```
<input type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text"
    (ngModelChange)="clearFilter()" placeholder="Find"/>
```

vs **change**:

```
<input type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" 
    (change)="clearFilter()" placeholder="Find"/>
```

Comment: If you want to compare the two of them, maybe you can also add `(change)` and `(keyup)`

Comment: I don't want to compare those. I just want to know which one is best for performance ?

Comment: Yeah there is no comparison . If you are using ngModel you can use the later otherwise the first one . Its always preferred to avoid ngModel as that's two way data binding , hence bad for performance

Comment: Edited to put emphasis on "what's the difference" and "which is more performant" to remove subjectivity & voted to reopen.

Comment: In Angular 7, the (ngModelChange)="eventHandler()" will fire BEFORE the value bound to [(ngModel)]="value" is changed while the (change)="eventHandler()" will fire AFTER the value bound to [(ngModel)]="value" is changed.

Comment: By the way, the (change) event is fired only when the focus leaves the input. If you want an event fired after each key-press, you can use the (input) event.

Comment: @CAK2 actually it depends on the ordering of the HTML: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28107

Answer (score 724, accepted):

`(change)` event bound to classical input change event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

You can use (change) event even if you don't have a model at your input as

```html
<input (change)="somethingChanged()">
```

`(ngModelChange)` is the `@Output` of ngModel directive. It fires when the model changes. You cannot use this event without ngModel directive.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L124

As you discover more in the source code, `(ngModelChange)` emits the new value.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L169

So it means you have ability of such usage:

```html
<input (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">
```

```js
modelChanged(newObj) {
    // do something with new value
}
```

Basically, it seems like there is no big difference between two, but `ngModel` events gains the power when you use `[ngValue]`.

```html
  <select [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" name="data">
      <option *ngFor="let currentData of allData" [ngValue]="currentData">
          {{data.name}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

```js
dataChanged(newObj) {
    // here comes the object as parameter
}
```

assume you try the same thing without "`ngModel` things"

```html
<select (change)="changed($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let currentData of allData" [value]="currentData.id">
        {{data.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

```js
changed(e){
    // event comes as parameter, you'll have to find selectedData manually
    // by using e.target.data
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I am using change event with ngmodel object?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I've improved the answer. You can still use change event with ngModel object, but change event passes event parameter, ngModelChange event passes new value.

Comment: Yeah +1 . But I have a problem with ngmodelchange, when you  clear all the values from text box by using ctr + A. then ngModelChange does not trigger .

Comment: `<input (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">` is not right, `[ngModel]` is required.

Comment: Any scenario faced in which (change) dosen't fire while selecting dropdown value for the first time ?

Comment: Something, you cannot do an `(change)`, in this case, you can do a `(onClick)="yourFunction(youParameter)"`

Comment: Change event fires when you remove the focus from input text after changing the content. On other hand ngModelChange will trigger with each input change. i.e if you start typing 'abc' ngModelChange will get triggered 3 times and once you remove focus from this field your change event gets fired.

Comment: Genreally, I really don't see the point of adding existing browser functionality on top of existing browser functionality. Same way to use it, different name, probably less functionality than the existing browser method. I feel this way about a lot of what angular tries to achieve. The answer seems good, I just don't understand why we need this.

Comment: Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event , it's `e.target.value` instead of `e.target.data` for `(change)` event

Comment: In option tag, Is {{data.name}} o {{currentData.name}}?

Comment: A small correction (data -> value):
`changed(e: Event){
    // event comes as parameter, you'll have to find selectedData manually
    // by using e.target.value`
}

Answer (score 152):

In Angular 7, the `(ngModelChange)="eventHandler()"` will fire **before** the value bound to `[(ngModel)]="value"` is changed while the `(change)="eventHandler()"` will fire **after** the value bound to `[(ngModel)]="value"` is changed.

Comment: I justed tested in Angular 7.1 and the value from the ngModel is updated before the event is called. So that's what I use

Comment: It worked in angular 6 as well. +1 for saving my time :)

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? According to the Angular [Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) `ngModelChange` fires after the view model updates.

Comment: @rage I didn't read the Angular docs regarding this issue.  I wrote this answer at the end of 2018 based on what I saw in the Chrome debugger at the time.

Comment: In the latest documentation of angular this case is described: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#data-flow-in-template-driven-forms

Comment: In Angular 7.2, indeed the `(ngModelChange)` event is fired **before** the value is changed and `(change)` **after** it has changed. Thanks for the info, super helpful!

Comment: "    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7."  https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Comment: I feel it's safer to not rely on details like the ordering of _ngModel_ and _ngModelChange_ in your template code, and instead use `[ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value = $event; eventHandler()"`. Note that I am not using the two-way binding syntax (banana in a box).

Comment: Why would someone want an function to fire before the value bound to the model has changed?

Comment: In angular 10 both change and ngModel change appear to fire before the value is updated. How do I get either to fire AFTER the value is updated?

Comment: @asma-rahim-ali-jafri One reason to evaluate the function before the model update is to allow validation logic to prevent the input from updating by issuing an event.preventDefault()

Comment: It's Still true in angular 10

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234

Answer (score 59):

As I have found and wrote in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544086/angular-2-ngmodelchange-old-value/57195920#57195920) topic  - this applies to angular < 7 (not sure how it is in 7+)

Just for the future

we need to observe that `[(ngModel)]="hero.name"` is just a short-cut that can be de-sugared to: `[ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event"`.

So if we de-sugar code we would end up with:

`<select (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()" [ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event">`

or

`<[ngModel]="hero.name" (ngModelChange)="hero.name = $event" select (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()">`

If you inspect the above code you will notice that we end up with 2 `ngModelChange` events and those need to be executed in some order.

Summing up: **If you place `ngModelChange` before `ngModel`, you get the `$event` as the new value, but your model object still holds previous value.**
If you place it after `ngModel`, the model will already have the new value.

[SOURCE](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I had this problem until I found your explanation

Comment: This made my day!. I did not know about the order of ngModel and ngModelChange makes behavior change. Thanks a lot

Comment: The sequence of the ngModel and ngModelChange is still relevant in for angular 10+. What a bad gotcha!

Comment: How come it's ```hero.name = $event``` and not ```hero.name = $event.value``` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```$event.target.value``` instead of ```$event.value```

Answer (score 18):

**1 -** `(change)` is bound to the HTML onchange event. The documentation about HTML onchange says the following :

> Execute a JavaScript when a user changes the selected option of a `<select>` element

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

**2 -** As stated before, `(ngModelChange)` is bound to the model variable binded to your input.

**So, my interpretation is :**

- `(change)` triggers when the **user** changes the input
- `(ngModelChange)` triggers when the model changes, whether it's consecutive to a user action or not

Answer (score 14):

As per my experience `(change)` and `(ngModelChange)` has two different usage.

1. `(ngModelChange)` triggers when HTML renders, user changed the value of that element.
2. `(change)` triggers when user changes the value and leave the element focus.

Usage:

1. `(ngModelChange)`: when you have critical things that depends on html any type of changes that you have to handle.
2. `(change)`: When you have to handle only value changes done by user.

Note: Be careful while using the `(ngModelChange)` because sometimes it will give you maximum call stack issue and your form will stuck.

Comment: This is what I've also realized from testing. And it is very important because if you want to reduce overhead, you could use change, since it is triggered only when the user leaves the focus of the input, and if there was a change. Thanks.

Comment: correct, thanks for comment

It will help others to understand

Answer (score 0):

----- **(change)** -----

(change) is the Angular equivalent to the JavaScript event handler:

```
addEventListener('change', (event) => {})
onchange = (event) => {}
```

For more see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

----- **(ngModelChange)** -----

To understand (ngModelChange) you should first understand **banana in a box (BIAB)** syntax:

```
<input name="surname" [(ngModel)]="surname">
```

BIAB provides two way binding ... if the controller variable changes it updates the view and if the bound value in the view changes it updates the controller variable.

The following is **100% exactly** the same as BIAB:

```
<input name="surname" [ngModel]="surname" (ngModelChange)="updateSurname($event)">

updateSurname(surname) {
  this.surname = surname
}
```

However, the use of `ngModelChange` gives the flexibility to do something different to the default BIAB behaviour. For example:

```
// example 1 - you can log
updateSurname(surname) {
  console.log(surname)
  this.surname = surname
}

// example 2 - you can modify
updateSurname(surname) {
  this.surname = surname + ' hello'
}
```