# how can i use Angular focusout with if condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, focusout

This is my input field

```
<input 
(keyup.enter)="save()" 
(focusout)="save()" 
class="editinput custom_story_input" 
type="text" 
placeholder="Create a new one"
id="tbtfeild"
value="" [(ngModel)]="childTaskmodel.childtitle"
#childtitle="ngModel"
name="childtitle" />
```

From the above input field, I don't have any problem with **enter** if the field is empty it shows the error message

Coming to **focus out** it should only work if there is any data present in the input field how can i do this..?

i want something like this:

```
  <input *ngIf (focusout)="childtitle.val != '' ? save() : '' " >
```

Comment: Instead of handling `(keyup.enter)` and `(focusout)`, you could handle `(change)`.

Comment: can you provide any reference to that, i use to do that in javascript, but i don't know how to handle in Angular 4

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44840735/1009922). Replace `(keyup.enter)="save()"` with `(change)="save()"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan not to be a pain in *where tou think*, but change is an event that is bound to `select` attributes. You should instead use `(input)`

Comment: @trichetriche - `(input)` would be the equivalent of `(ngModelChange)`. `(change)` is what the OP wants to do in his code. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpaznv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welll you can do that :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="childtitle" (focusout)="childtitle ? save() : null">
```

test it : unless your input has a value, it won't work.

**EDIT** Explanation :

you first bind your variable to the input with `[(ngModel)]="childtitle"` : this allows you to let angular know that he has to watch for changes on that variable.

Next, you bind an HTML event to this input, with `(focusout)="childtitle ? save() : null"`. As a value, you write a ternary operator : this is a one-liner for a `if ... else ...` condition. In that ternary, you state that if this input has a value (this is a **truthy** value, a Javascript concept, you will find more on the internet), then you can run the function. If not, then you just run `null`, which ... Does nothing.

Comment: It worked like a magic thanks for the help. I will accept in 5mins, can you please explain the answer little bit.

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't available this weekend, I explained my answer in an edit, feel free to see it

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `save()` function, check your model `childTaskmodel.childtitle`. If it's empty, don't continue. If you want different behaviour for your `keyup.enter` and focusout, just create two methods inside controller.