# Angular ag-grid cell renderer checkbox not refresh value

Tags: angular, ag-grid, cellrenderer, ag-grid-ng2

I created cell renderer for checkbox input but when I click checkbox it change the value inside but not on the cell.

See plunker example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z2BrMcFtneZTeWwnxjFs?p=preview)

`refresh` method should be called on change but somehow it is not.

`onCellClicked` function returns still same value no matter how I click on checkbox.

I tried `cellEditor: 'agRichSelect'` with two possible values `true` and `false` which worked fine but I need checkbox.

Thaks for any ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular)**, for tracking changes of `ngModel` you need to use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(onChange)`.

**Second**, you shouldn't use `params.value` for `ngModel` binding, `params` - is a part of `grid`, so just avoid mixing things and keep it separately.

**[Third](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component)**, in `refresh` function inside `cellRenderer` you shouldn't update `params`, `refresh` function used internally for `grid`.

```
// Mandatory - Get the cell to refresh. Return true if the refresh succeeded, otherwise return false.
// If you return false, the grid will remove the component from the DOM and create
// a new component in its place with the new values.
refresh(params: any): boolean;
```

**Fourth**, if you want to update value inside `cellRenderer` you should use `ICellEditorComp` interface instead of `ICellRendererComp`(`ICellRendererAngularComp` and `ICellEditorAngularComp` on `Angular` case)

**Fifth**, you forgot to setup checkbox field `editable: true` in `columnDefs`

**And the last one** - you've just created checkbox (out of `grid` scope) which is looked like a working sample, but it's not.

You need to understand the full edit process if `ag-grid`, so just check here details about [cell rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/), [cell editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/) and much more.

And [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/) you can see how [exactly](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.js) custom checkbox renderer will work :

```
function booleanCellRenderer(params) {
    var valueCleaned = booleanCleaner(params.value);
    if (valueCleaned === true) {
        return "<span title='true' class='ag-icon ag-icon-tick content-icon'></span>";
    } else if (valueCleaned === false) {
        return "<span title='false' class='ag-icon ag-icon-cross content-icon'></span>";
    } else if (params.value !== null && params.value !== undefined) {
        return params.value.toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```