# How to filter second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown? - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a two dropdowns that looks like this:

[image]

so my plan is to load all subcategories, but I would like to display in dropdown only these which are related to selected Category ( that one which contain ParentId as Id of selected Category).

And here is my code:

```
<!--Category-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Category:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleCategory" #articleCategory="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="article.mainCategory">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="category" *ngFor="let category of mainGroups">{{category.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Subcategory-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Sub category:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="subCategory" #subCategory="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="article.subCategory">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="subcategory" *ngFor="let subcategory of subCategories">{{subcategory.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I need to post typescript code please tell me, but Here I got values from database, and this is only problem for me, how to filter Subcategory based on Category selection.

Thanks guys
Cheers!

Comment: this might help, basically use the `change` or `ngModelChange` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Comment: @Ric I thought about *ngIf="subcategory.parentId = mainCategory.Id"somewhere but I get an error :/

Comment: you could use the `change` event to get the value of your category, then `filter` the values of your `subCategories` based on your conditions

Comment: Change subCategory according to change in value of mainCategory.

eg.

 this.form.get('account_type').valueChanges.subscribe(val => { } )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some of the comments pointed out, listen to the change of you first select element to dynamically generate the options for you second select with a `filter`.

Something like:

```
filterSubById(id) {
    return this.subCategories.filter(item => item.parentId === id);
}
```

I've made a quick [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ew9rl) to show how.

**EDIT**

The way this works is that the selected value from the first select is bound to the `mainCategory` property of your component. Hence, `mainCategory` changes depending on what the user selects from the first menu. The second select dynamically loads the options depending on what the user chooses on the first one; this is accomplished with a `filter` function that returns all the elements in the `subCategories` array whose `parentId` matches the `id` of the option selected in the first menu.

Comment: can you explain this little bit please, I thought that there should be added code on main category, when user press main category to filter sub category, everything works but I don't understand how come :P Thanks

Comment: Sure, I've added some comments :)

Comment: I understand everything but I don't understand how come first selection fires up filterSubById which is part of second selection, can you show me the code where making selection on first dropdown causing selection of second..

Comment: The beauty of angular is that we don't have to explicitly call `filterSubByid()`. Angular is smart enough to recognise that the function has to be called whenever `mainCategory` changes, and when we select an option from the first dropdown we are in fact changing `mainCategory`

Comment: @bugs Thanks it worked for me. Could you please elaborate little more on how does the change on first dropdown calls `filterSubByid()` function?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very broad question with many correct answers.
I would say the best thing to do is to add (change)="filterSubcategories()" to your select element, that will trigger the filterSubcategories() function, where you can select the correct subcategories, based on your article.mainCategory.

```
 <!--Category-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Category:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" (change)="filterSubcategories()" name="articleCategory" #articleCategory="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="article.mainCategory">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="category" *ngFor="let category of mainGroups">{{category.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```