# how to filter mat-select by selecting value of other mat-select in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have two mat-select and want to filter second mat-select by selected value in first mat-select:
html code is :

```
<mat-label>products</mat-label>
         <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width">
         <mat-select  #captionlist>
             <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of list_product.data" [value]="p">
                {{ p.description }}
             </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
                      
         <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width">
         <mat-label>brand</mat-label>
             <mat-select  #brandlist>
                  <mat-option  *ngFor="let m of list_brands.data" [value]="m">
                     {{ m.BDesc }}
                  </mat-option>
             </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
```

pls,help me ,what write in type script to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown? - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899972/how-to-filter-second-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-first-dropdown-angular)

Comment: no i can't do this ,please help according my code