# Disable Angular 5 Input fields correct way

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms

I have a FormGroup that was created like that:

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email]
});
```

When an event occurs I want to disable those inputs, so, in the HTML I added:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="name" autocomplete="off" [disabled]="isDisabled" required>

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="email" email="true" autocomplete="off" [disabled]="isDisabled" required>
```

Where `isDisabled` is a variable I toggle to `true` when the said event happens.
As you can imagine, I get the message:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

So, with the example this warning shows and with a little search I found that I should declare my controls like:

```
name: [{ value: '', disabled: this.isDisabled }, Validators.required]
```

The problem is: **It is not toggling between disabled/enabled when the variable changes between `true`/`false`**
How is the correct way of having a variable controlling if an input is enabled or disabled?

I don't want to do it manually (ex: `this.form.controls['name'].disable()`) because it doesn't seems a very reactive way, I would have to call it inside a good amount of methods. Probably not a good practice.

Thx

Comment: I use the (change)="" in conjunction with [(ngModel)] works like a charms also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular) SO post out pretty awesome IMHO

Comment: btw you don't need both `formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="name" ` on your inputs

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can change the assignment of the variable to a setter method so that you'd have:

```
set isDisabled(value: boolean) {
 this._isDisabled = value;
 if(value) {
  this.form.controls['name'].disable();
 } else {
    this.form.controls['name'].enable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? This looks a lot more like Kludge than a solution.

Comment: this is not a good approach, because the user can delete this attribute via the browser, in which case it will change in the data in the model?  for example, I have a form where I saved user information, I did a add disabled attributes some fields, and I want to exclude the disabled one when saving the form.

Answer (score 21):

For input use [readonly] rather than [disabled] and it'll work

Comment: Yes, it will work, but attributes `readonly` and `disabled`, have really different meaning.

Comment: For anyone curious: "The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls can still function and are still focusable, whereas disabled controls can not receive focus and are not submitted with the form and generally do not function as controls until they are enabled." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

And it also changes the cursor. Use `cursor: default;` and `tabindex="-1"` to make it more similar to the disabled state.

Answer (score 13):

One solution is creating a directive and using binding for that as described in [here](https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110)

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }

}
```

then

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off" [disableControl]="isDisabled" required>
```

### NOTE:

Doesn't work with Ivy

Comment: In Ivy (default since Angular 9) there's an error "Injected ngControl doesn't contain control property" (before Ivy it was ok).  I found solution (although looking awkward) here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35330

Comment: @jurekskowron thanks for heads up, it's worth to post you working example as answer

Comment: Thanks @jurekskowron. The mentioned solution worked for me in Angular 10. I have posted the same as a new answer.

Answer (score 12):

---

Disable TextBox in Angular 7

```
<div class="center-content tp-spce-hdr">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mx-0 mt-4">
      <div class="col-12" style="padding-right: 700px;" >
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
                <input [disabled]="true" type="text" id="email" name="email" 
                [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to disable an form control. With reactive forms you should never disable an input from the template. So in whatever method in your component you are calling you should disable the input like this:

```
this.form.get('name').disable();
```

Comment: I can still right-click the control, view source and remove the `disabled` attribute, making it enabled again.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code on your ts file.

All controls:

```
this.form.disable()
this.form.enable()
```

Some controls

```
this.form.get('first').disable()
this.form.get('first').enable()
```

Or Initial set method.

```
first: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required)
```

Comment: For initial set method, it should be `first: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required)` as I tried. You have to specify the key(value) for the value.

Answer (score 3):

In Reactive Form you can disable all form fields by `this.form.disable()`.
In Template Driven Form you can disable all form fields by `this.myform.form.disable()` where myForm is `@ViewChild('form') myForm`;

Answer (score 1):

Not the clean or dry'st I imagine. Bu I tried the "set method" and didn't work out of the box...

Needed some refactoring () => {simpleVersion} (hope it helps someone)

component.ts

```
...
  // standard stuff...
  form: FormGroup;
  isEditing = false;
...
  // build the form...
  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.FormBuilder.group({
      key: [{value:'locked', disabled: !this.isEditing}],
      name: [],
      item: [],
      active: [false]
    })
  }
  // map the controls to "this" object
  // => i.e. now you can refer to the controls directly (ex. this.yourControlName)
  get key() { return <FormControl>this.form.get('key') }
  get name() { return <FormControl>this.form.get('name') }
...
  // ----------------------------------------
  //     THE GRAND FINALÉ - disable entire form or individual controls
  // ----------------------------------------
  toggleEdit() {
    if(!this.isEditing) {
      this.key.enable();      // controls
      this.name.enable();
      // this.form.enable();     // the form

      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
    } else {
      this.key.disable();      // the controls
      this.name.disable();     // the controls

      // this.form.disable();     // or the entire form

      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
    }
   }
```

& perhaps overkill on the HTML logic, so hope you find the bonus integrated ngClass toggle just as helpful.

component.html (toggle button)

```
<div class="btn-group" (click)="toggleEdit()">
           <label
             class="btn"
             role="button"
             [ngClass]="{'btn-success': isEditing,
                         'btn-warning': !isEditing}">toggle edit
           </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by creating a `directive` and using `binding` for that worked for me in `Angular 10` is described in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35330)

***Template:***

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput class="form-control" formControlName="NameText" [disableControl]="condition" type="text">
</mat-form-field>
```

***TypeScript:***

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[opDisabled]'
})
export class DisabledDirective {
  @Input()
  set opDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    setTimeout(() => this.ngControl.control[action]());
  }

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

Comment: I am using element.nativeElment in a Directive and using setTimeout solved my problem. But I don't know why setTimeout is helping in this case?

Answer (score 1):

As control can't be accessed in **reactive forms**. This is due to migration to **Ivy**. You can use can access the html attribute directly and specify your condition. See this issue [#35330](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35330) for more details and alternative methods.

```
[attr.disabled]="true || false"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can create set and get method to achieve conditionally enable/disable functionality for Angular material Reactive Forms:**

*// 1st Step:

```
 set isDisabled(value:boolean) {
      if(value){
       this.form.controls['Form controller name'].disable(); //you can keep empty if you don't add controller name

      } 
      else{
       this.form.controls['Form controller name'].enable();
      }
    }
```

*// 2nd Step: Add conditions in getter*

```
get isDisabled(){
  return condition ? true : false;
}
```

*// 3rd Step*

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
  name: [{value: '', disabled: this.isDisabled }, [Validators.required]],
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that enables a control on click.

```
  controlClick(control: any) {
      this.form.controls[control.ngControl.name].enable();
  }
```

Originally i was using

```
  control.disabled = false;
```

But this did not work for controls with `<input>` for example in my `mat-chip-list`.

I use FormGroup and disable each control in the constructor

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data
  ) {
    this.data = data;
    this.multiEdit = data.multiSelect;

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      autoArchive: new FormControl({
        value:
          this.getPreFill(data.selectedPolicy.autoArchive, this.multiEdit),
        disabled: true
        /*, Validators.required*/
      }),
```

...

```
  <mat-form-field (click)="controlClick(retrieveChipList)">
      <mat-chip-list #retrieveChipList formControlName="retrieveChipList">
        <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let email of data.selectedPolicy.retrieveEmailsToBeNotified" 
          (removed)="remove(email)" [selectable]="selectable"
          [removable]="removable" 
        >
          {{ email }}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input
        placeholder="Retrieve Emails to be Notified" 
        formControlName="retrieveChipList"
          [matChipInputFor]="retrieveChipList"
          [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addRetrieveEmails($event)"
        />
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove [disabled]="isDisabled" from input fields and add ng-disabled="all" and in the event field add ng-model="all"

```
<body ng-app="">
Click here to disable all the form fields:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">


<input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="name" autocomplete="off" ng-disabled="all" required>

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="email" email="true" autocomplete="off"  ng-disabled="all" required>

</body>
```