# ng-disabled is not working on an input checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a very simple html, only containing

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ member.firstName }}" (click)="tick($event)" ng-disabled="true" />
```

and yet the `ng-disabled` doesn't work, i.e. checkbox remains enabled.

If I change it to:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ member.firstName }}" (click)="tick($event)" disabled />
```

it works, i.e. the checkbox is disabled.

What is wrong with the first line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Angular 5 Input fields correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220643/disable-angular-5-input-fields-correct-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's angular it should be **`[disabled]`**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ member.firstName }}" (click)="tick($event)" [disabled]="true" />
```

Comment: That works, but my goal was to have something like `[disabled]="enableCheckboxes"` where `enableCheckboxes` is a class variable set to true or false, which now doesn't work.

Comment: @Obay No issue with your code please check the value of enableCheckboxes is true or false or undefined.

Answer (score -1):

What code editor are you using? I used https://www.plnkr.co and it worked fine.
And as hardik said above, are you using the script tag?
`<input type="checkbox" value="{{ member.firstName }}" (click)="tick($event)" ng-disabled="true" />`

Answer (score -2):

are you including the script as follows in your index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

if you don't include this script the `ng-disabled` will not work as `ng-disabled` is an angular-js directive.