# How do I access an ngOnChanges field?

Tags: html, angular

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="khatianNumber" required [(ngModel)]="big.khatianNumberP1" name="khatianNumber" #khatianNumber="ngModel">

<p id="parapart" align="center">/</p>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="khatianNumber2" required [(ngModel)]="big.khatianNumberP2" name="khatianNumber2" #khatianNumber1="ngModel">
```

And my Angular looks something like this,

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
isRequesting = false;
steps = [];
model = {
  khatianNumber: '',
};

big = {
  khatianNumberP1: '',
  khatianNumberP2: '',
}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if (changes['big.plotNumberP1']){
        alert("hi");
    }
}
}
```

I've never used angular like this, I usually had to use scopes and controllers.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my HTML or am I using the models wrong? I am new to Angular and would greatly appreciate if someone could clear this doubt!

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try like that,

if thet below one is not working means try change your form template driven to model driven forms(Reactive forms)

The below one i have used Reactive forms its works for me

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange})
    {
        if(changes.hasOwnProperty('big.khatianNumberP1')){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` is used for data passed from parent to child components. For catching model changes you need to use an event listener which is `ngModelChange` or you can basically use the `change` listener if you have a basic form. See this post for details about the difference between them, and how to use both: [(change) vs (ngModelChange) in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an action when there is a change in a form element, it is best to separate `[(ngModel)]="big.khatianNumberP1"` into `[ngModel]="big.khatianNumberP1"` and `(ngModelChange)="numberP1Changed()"`.

Then, in your component code, you can have a handler which does whatever you need:

```
export class RegistrationComponent {
    isRequesting = false;
    steps = [];
    model = {
        khatianNumber: '',
    };
    big = {
        khatianNumberP1: '',
        khatianNumberP2: '',
    }

    numberP1Changed() {
       alert("hi - new value - " + this.big.khatianNumberP1);
    }
}
```