# (ngModelChange) does not update the UI for specific input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I have an input field where the user can enter the rate of something.

When the user enters a value, I want it to be displayed after rounding it off and then the updated value to be stored on the backing model in `ts` file.

Using an Angular pipe isn't good for this since a pipe in one directional and the updated value won't be reflected on the model.

So to make it bidirectional, I'm doing the following:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="model.rate" (ngModelChange)="model.rate=roundRate($event)" name="rate" />
```

The `roundDate` function looks like this

```
roundRate(value) {
    return Math.round(value);
}
```

Now when I enter values like 5.6, 7.8, 9.5 etc they're all rounded off, displayed and stored on the model to 6, 8 and 10 respectively, which is the expected behavior.

The problem starts when I enter 2.1, 3.4, 5.3 etc. In this case, the `roundRate` function gets called and it returns the value after rounding off. But the values shown on screen are still the old values (2.1, 3.4, 5.3)

I inspected the `input` element on Chrome and found that the `ng-reflect-model` property was getting updated to the expected values (2, 3, 5).

```
<input _ngcontent-c39="" name="rate" type="text" ng-reflect-name="rate" ng-reflect-model="5" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here and despite the `ng-reflect-model` property getting updated why the screen still shows the old values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use (change) instead of (ngModelChange), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Comment: Isn't your code resulting in an infinite loop? Because you are re-assigning to the source that is emitting an event in a handler. Or may be it won't when you re-assign the previous value.

Comment: @SteveRuben, Can you please explain how will that help?

Comment: @AmitChigadani, No it isn't goining into infinite loop. The the event triggers only when the user inputs something. In that event, the new value gets assinged. And it waits for user to update it.

Comment: @Yogesh, check if my answer helps.

Comment: @Yogesh it's good now ?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Yes, it works! Can you explain why my code failed for values like 3.1, 4.3 and worked for 5.6, 9.8 etc

Comment: @SteveRuben Yep, seeing the code helped.

Comment: @Yogesh have a look at the answer, I covered *the why aspect* in technical terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a cleaner implementation, just use the `(change)` `@Output` property and `[(ngModel)]`. The implementation of `roundRate` will change something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  model = { rate: null };

  roundRate() {
    this.model.rate = Math.round(+this.model.rate);
  }
}
```

And in template:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.rate" (change)="roundRate()" name="rate" />
```

**PS:** This will update the value only once you `blur` from your input field

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchanges-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Can you please tell me what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: @Yogesh, I'm still analyzing it. I'll let you know if I find anything substantial.

Comment: Please do let me know. I'm curious.

Comment: @SiddAjmera buy (change) can only invoke once after you trigger blur .

Answer (score 15):

Begin with a closer look at the [`ngModel` directive API](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts), you will see that `ngModel` is [`@Input` binding](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L119) which accepts some value as `model` variable. At the time of initializing `ngModel` control it [creates `FormControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L110) implicitly.

```
public readonly control: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

The magic of updating `model` value happens from [`ngOnChanges` hook](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L176), this way it syncs the view value with the `model` value. If you take a closer look at the `ngOnChanges` hook, you will find that it validates the input and applies other checks as well, afterwards it strictly checks if the value of `ngModel` has really changed using the `isPropertyUpdated` method.

[**ngOnChanges**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L176-L187) - `ngModel` directive

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this._checkForErrors();
    if (!this._registered) this._setUpControl();
    if ('isDisabled' in changes) {
      this._updateDisabled(changes);
    }

    if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
      this._updateValue(this.model); // helps to update 
      this.viewModel = this.model;
    }
}

private _updateValue(value: any): void {
    resolvedPromise.then(() => { 
      // set value will set form control
      this.control.setValue(value, {emitViewToModelChange: false}); 
    });
}
```

But, to make it happen, Angular should recognize the changes during change detection cycle. And, since we haven't changed our model, it won't trigger the ngOnChanges hook:

[image]

What I explained till now was the API part. Lets come back to the question.

Try the below [snippet in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-manh24?file=src/app/app.component.html), what our expectation would be. On input value change, it should set that value to `10` itself.

```
<input type="text" 
  [ngModel]="model.rate" 
  (ngModelChange)="model.rate = 10"
  name="rate" />
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't happen in that way, you will see that on initially typing any number, it will change the input value to `10` and later whatever you type will keep on appending to the number input. Ahh, wondering why?

Let's go back again to the original question,

```
<input type="text" 
  [ngModel]="model.rate" 
  (ngModelChange)="model.rate=roundRate($event)"
  name="rate" />
 {{model.rate}}
```

`ngModel` is used as a one way binding. Expected behavior is, whatever values assigned to the `model.rate` should be reflected inside the `input`. Let's try to enter 1.1, you will see that it shows us the value `1.1`. Now try to enter `1.2`, this results in `1`. Wondering why? But certainly `model.rate` bindings update correctly.
Similarly Check for `4.6` and `4.8`. They result in 5, which works perfect.

Let's break down the above example, what happens when you try to enter `1.1`.

1. type `1`   => model.rate becomes `1`
2. type `1.`  => model.rate stays `1`
3. type `1.1` => model.rate stays `1`

Eventually when you type `1.1` or `1.2` the model value stays `1` since we `Math.round` the value. Since it isn't updating the `model.rate` value, whatever you enter further is just ignored by the `ngModel` binding, and is shown inside the `input` field.

Checking for `4.6`, `4.8` works perfectly. Why? break it down step wise

1. type `4`   => model.rate becomes `4`
2. type `4.`  => model.rate stays `4`
3. type `4.6` => model.rate **becomes** `5`

Over here, when you enter `4.6` in textbox, the `Math.round` value becomes `5`. which is a change in the `model.rate`(ngModel) value and would result in an update in the `input` field value.

Now start reading the answer again, the technical aspect explained initially should be clear as well.

> Note: While reading an answer follow the links provided to snippet, it
> may help you understand it more precisely.

---

To make it working you can try updating your fields on `blur`/`change` where this event fires on the focus out of `fields` like [`Sid's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427571/ngmodelchange-does-not-update-the-ui-for-specific-input/53427926#53427926). It works because you're updating the model once when the field is focused out.

**But** it works only once. To keep updating constantly we can do a trick like this:

```
this.model.rate = new String(Math.round(value));
```

which will result in a new object reference each time we round our value.

[Snippet in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchanges-eg-upzz5p?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Suresh, glad to know it helped ;)

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thanks Panjak. 

Comment: I would say that the main reason here is how Angular change detection mechanism works under the hood. It won't update property or trigger ngOnChanges hook if value hasn't changed. We can see it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchanges-eg-nccjh1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Also blur/change event will help only once. If we type 1.2 then click outside the input value will become 1, after that if we try to change the value from 1 to 1.2 and trigger blur that value won't be changed to 1. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchanges-eg-jvvzrs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: But if we will change the value like `this.model.rate = new String(Math.round(value));` then `change/blur` events will definitely work  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchanges-eg-upzz5p?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @PankajParkar Now I got to know why that didn't work. @yurzui Yep, the ``(change)` event also worked only once.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted to say @yurzui . Feel free to edit answer :)

Comment: awesome explanation @PankajParkar

Comment: didn't read the whole answer because wtf angular but the solution works. Why does anyone use this framework?

Answer (score 1):

> In Angular change detection strategy help to reflect changes on UI.

Please use below code:

**Step 1:** Import `ChangeDetectorRef` in your component

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef} from angular/core';
```

**Step 2:** Create instance of `ChangeDetectorRef` on constructor.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){
}
```

**Step 3:** Call where you are updating value.

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have called the detectChanges() method and it worked for me!

Comment: @ZakiMohammed Where did you call this method?

Answer (score 1):

We can also obtain its value using $event and not using ngModel-

component.html

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="width:100px;height:38px;"><input type = "text"  (change)="enterDirectRowNumberResponse(data,$event.target.value)"></td></tr>
</tbody
</table>
```

component.ts

```
enterDirectRowNumberResponse(data,event){
        console.log ("Inside enterDirectRowNumberResponse",event)
        console.log ("data = ", data );
}
```