# Angular - prevent entering number outside of range in input type="number"

Tags: angular, input, angular-ngmodel, html-input

In my project I have an `input type="number"` where the user should enter a number between 1(always) and another number. I want to restrict the UI input element, is such way that only numbers in that range can be entered. My code so far:

.html:

```
<p>Allowed values are 1 - {{max}}</p>
<input type="number" (input)="input($event)" />
```

.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  readonly max = 5;

  input(event: Event) {
    const inputElem = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (+inputElem.value < 1) {
      inputElem.value = '1';
    } else if (+inputElem.value > this.max) {
      inputElem.value = this.max.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbkgrx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

The code works as I wish but I wonder if there is an Angular way of doing this, with `[(ngModel)]` or `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`. I tried some things, but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

it's very similar to this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228833/input-value-not-change-along-with-ngmodel-update/69335039#69335039)

```
  readonly max = 5;
  mynumber = 2;
  validateInput(e: any, input: any = null) {
    let value = +e;
    if (value < 1) value = 1;
    if (value > this.max) value = this.max;
    this.mynumber = value;
    if (input.value != value) {
      const start = input.selectionStart ? input.selectionStart - 1 : -1;
      input.value = value;
      if (start>=0) input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd = start;
    }
  }

<input type="number" #input [ngModel]="mynumber" 
     (ngModelChange)="validateInput($event,input)" />
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyz4t8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)