# Angular 4 Readonly input change detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I have following code with readonly input.  am trying to change the value if this readonly input from TS File, but, I am unable to detect change from any function. Below is the example.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" readonly [(ngModel)]="field1" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
```

ngModelChange is not working in this senario.

Comment: Do you want to capture what  user types ?

Comment: Have you removed the readonly property and and checked whether the onChange() triggers or not?

Comment: you are using `ngModelChange` also `ngModel` why two, Two-way bindings?

Comment: Try to use (change) instead of (ngModelChange)

Comment: I want to perform certain functionality based on value change. I tried to remove readonly, in that case if user enters value in that particular field, it works. But my requirement is to catch the value changed by TS file in readonly input and perform functionality. I hope it is clear.

Comment: @WomenWhoCode Do you change the field1 value from another function? If you are using "readonly", it means you cannot type anything on the input. So, how come you are expecting the input can changed? need to know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `(change)` instead of `(ngModelChange)`.

Here is [some explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular) to help you understand this.

Comment: Hi @WomenWhoCode, i will continue on the comment above to know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use input like this:

```
(input)="handle($event)"
```

And Handle event in your typescript accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`FormControl` to the rescue!!

FormControls and Reactive forms are great and it will save your day! :)

Mark `ReactiveFormsModule` in your app.module, import `FormControl` to your component aaand... For demo I used a simple timeout to change the value to trigger the `valueChanges`:

```
myControl = new FormControl('')

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.myControl.setValue('something');
  }, 2000);

  this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('changed!')
  });
}
```

And template:

```
<input type="text" readonly [formControl]="myControl">
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8vqik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

*P.S if this is input is part of a template driven form, this wouldn't work, since `ngModel` and `formControl` shouldn't be used together. So you would be notified of that. So in that case I suggest you go reactive way ;)*