# Angular - Removing two way binding on NgModel?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

how do I remove two way binding with [(ngModel)] in angular?

I want a seperate handler for setting the value, and another for changing it. So I can have side-effects

e.g.

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="selectedEscrowOffering" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="escrowFormatter">
```

in Vue, models were considered syntatic sugar.

Could I seperate out the two way into a directive and onChangeHandler?

```
 <input [value]="selectedEscrowOffering" (change)="someFunctionName($event)" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="escrowFormatter">
```

Comment: It should work just fine. For the initial beta of Angular, I used this approach and only bound the value of ngModel (`[ngModel]`) and handled the change/blur event like you have above. There were race conditions when binding the ngModel change event (using `[()]`) and trying to call an event. Which event was invoked first was not consistent.

Comment: The `(change)` event here would be the input's change event, not an update from ngModel. The model would have to be manually updated in your `someFunctionName` event handler.

Comment: You should consider reading [the documentation on binding types](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-types-and-targets).

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to vue, you seperate the `@Output` and the `@Input` as follows: 
`<input (ngModelChange)="someFunctionName($event)" [ngModel]="mymodel">`

Comment: what's the different between `(ngModelChange)` and just `(change`)

Comment: @VincentTang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Related to the other answer by KLTR, this is how I got it to work:

This two way binding model:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedEscrowOffering"
```

can be broken down into the following:

```
<input [ngModel]="selectedEscrowOffering" (ngModelChange)="onChangeEscrowDropdown($event)>
```

On the typescript side, add the function that sets it. I had it on a typeahead, and it looked for an elements in the array of objects to match it

```
onChangeEscrowDropdown($event){

  if(typeof $event ==="object"){
    this.selectedEscrowOffering = $event
  }
}
```