# Angular2 [selected] doesn't work with [ngValue]

Tags: angular, angular8, angular2-forms

I am facing issue, where I cannot set team's club to `[selected]` option with `[ngValue]`. However, if I'm using `[value]` and `[selected]`, it set's team's club to the option, but I cannot pass object with `[value]`

**Here is my code:**

Using `[value]` and `[selected]`, which sets team's club to `[selected]` option, but I cannot pass object to the `[value]`

```
<select
    *ngIf="isEditing"
    name="club"
    #club="ngModel"
    [ngModel]="team?.club">
    Change club's logo
    <option
        *ngFor="let item of premierLeagueTeams"
        [value]="item"
        [selected]="item === team?.club">
        {{ item.club }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Using [ngValue], but options field doesn't have team's club when I start editing.

```
<select
    *ngIf="isEditing"
    class="team-club-change"
    name="club"
    #club="ngModel"
    [ngModel]="team?.club.clubName"
    (change)="changeTeam(club.value)">
    Change club's logo
    <option
        *ngFor="let item of premierLeagueTeams"
        [ngValue]="item">
        {{ item.clubName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

interfaces

```
export interface Team {
    name: string,
    club: Club,
    id: number
}

export interface Club {
    clubName: string, 
    logoURL: string,
    venue: string,
    city: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NgModel directive works as a bridge that enables "two-way binding" to HTML elements. Using "two-way binding" we can display a data property as well as update that property when the user makes changes & we can achieve this in both component and HTML elements.

**Pattern:** `ngModel` in property binding and `ngModelChange` in event binding. Link => [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

**Note:** If two-way binding is taking place at HTML element levels such as in input box or select box then we will use `ngModel` for target name as `[(ngModel)]`

**Moreover:** `[value]` supports string values, whereas
`[ngValue]` supports any type, and to use objects as value, use [ngValue] instead of [value].

**Possible Error:** This ngModel directive is defined in one of the Modules called Forms and by default this is not imported in to application. If you want to use `ngModel` or if you wanna build any kind of forms you need to explicitly import `FormsModule` in app.module.ts

Know more about two-way data binding and ngModel on these links [Link - 1](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-two-way-data-binding-ngmodel-example)  [Link - 2](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/components/app_structure_with_components/two_way_data_binding)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `(change)` You have to use `(ngModelChange)`.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45075106/4743730) has a very good explanation about both of them.

Comment: @НовиковМаксим Did that fix ur issue?

Comment: unfortunately, no