# Angular [(ngModel)] changing data after other events fire

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm not an expert on Angular events but here's my issue. If I run the following code I'm bassically updating the backend with the wrong information because `item.their_platform` doesn't change before `togglePlatform()` fires.

Template:

```
<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="togglePlatform()" [(ngModel)]="item.their_platform"></mat-checkbox>
```

TS:

```
 togglePlatform(){
      //update backend with the new value for item.their_platform
  }
```

I've solved the issue by using a timeout in the `togglePlatform` method, though I'm hoping there's a different event I can tie that method to that makes more sense in this scenario.

Is there a better event?
Is this a side effect of using mat-checkbox vs using vanilla Angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not rely on the order the execution as you are not always which arrives before.
In your case, solution should be:

```html
<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="togglePlatform($event)" [(ngModel)]="item.their_platform"></mat-checkbox>
```

```js
togglePlatform(value) {
     // update backend with the value, not item.their_platform
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `change` rather than `ngModelChange`. Because change fires after binding , ngModelChange fires before binding.

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="togglePlatform()" [(ngModel)]="item.their_platform"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Yes, I like this as well. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome and read this also to understand differance between  change andngModelChange. Basically ngModelChange fire before bind change fire after bind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular