# Cannot get value from time picker in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 17 for my frontend and I cannot get the value from the <igx-time-picker> to bind to my form. I don't believe its logging any value since even the function to log out the value doesn't seem to be getting called.

I'd love to understand what I'm doing wrong because I've tried everything!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<section class="listing-apply">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Create new event</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="applyForm" (submit)="submitEvent()">
    <label for="name">Event Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">

    <label for="description"> Event Description</label>
    <input id="description" type="text" formControlName="description">
    <select #event (change)="selectEventType(event.value)">
      <option default>What type of event is this?</option>
      <option>Work Event</option>
      <option>Social Event</option>
      <option>Task</option>
    </select>
    <mat-form-field>
      <!-- Date picker basic implementation -->
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker" formControlName="scheduledDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datepicker ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <!-- Date picker basic implementation -->
      <input matInput  [matDatepicker]="datepicker2" formControlName="dueDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datepicker2 ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <label for="selectedUsers">Select Users</label>
      <select  #userSelect (change)="selectUsers(userSelect.value)" multiple formControlName="attendees" id="selectedUsers" >
        <option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user.username">{{ user.username }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <mat-checkbox matInput  formControlName="reminderScheduled" > Send reminder notification 15 minutes before event start to all attendees?</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div>
    <igx-time-picker [(ngModel)]="date" #timePicker (change)="selectScheduledTime(timePicker.value)" mode="dialog" [inputFormat]="'hh:mm'" formControlName="scheduledTime">
      <label igxLabel>Home Time </label>
      <igx-picker-toggle igxSuffix>
        <igx-icon>home</igx-icon>
      </igx-picker-toggle>
      <igx-hint>{{date.toLocaleString()}}</igx-hint>
    </igx-time-picker>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div>
      <mat-card class="demo-inline-card">
        <mtx-calendar  (selectedChange)="selectedTime = $event" type="time" startView="clock" #timePicker (change)="selectScheduledTime(timePicker.value)">
        </mtx-calendar>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
    -->


    <button type="submit" class="primary">Apply now</button>
  </form>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import {Component, inject} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterOutlet} from "@angular/router";
import {EventService} from "../services/event.service";
import {CommonModule, DatePipe, NgForOf} from "@angular/common";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {Event} from '../model/event-interface';
import {MatCalendar, MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatNativeDateModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from "@angular/material/button-toggle";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {BrowserModule, HammerModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {EventAttendee} from "../model/event-attendee";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { MtxCalendar } from '@ng-matero/extensions/datetimepicker';
import { provideNativeDatetimeAdapter } from '@ng-matero/extensions/core';

import {
  IGX_TIME_PICKER_DIRECTIVES,
  IgxIconComponent,
  IgxPickerToggleComponent,
  IgxTimePickerComponent
} from 'igniteui-angular';
import {MatCard} from "@angular/material/card";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule, RouterOutlet, MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCalendar,
    MatCard,
    NgForOf,
    IGX_TIME_PICKER_DIRECTIVES,
    HammerModule, IgxTimePickerComponent, IgxPickerToggleComponent, IgxIconComponent,
    MtxCalendar,
    CommonModule,

  ],
  templateUrl: './event-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './event-form.component.css',
  providers: [provideNativeDatetimeAdapter()],
})
export class EventFormComponent {
    route: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
    eventService = inject(EventService);
    event: Event;
    router: Router;
    eventTypeHash: Map<String,String>;
    userList: EventAttendee[];
    selectedUsers: string[];
    attendees: string[];
    reminderScheduled: boolean;
    scheduledTime: string | null;
    date: Date = new Date();
    datePipe: DatePipe;
    selectedTime: Date | null = null;

    applyForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      description: new FormControl(''),
      scheduledDate: new FormControl(''),
      scheduledTime: new FormControl(''),
      dueDate: new FormControl(''),
      attendees: new FormControl([]),
      reminderScheduled: new FormControl(false),
    })


  constructor() {
      this.event = new Event('','','','', '');
      this.router = new Router();
      this.eventService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.userList = data;
    });
      this.selectedUsers = [];
      this.eventTypeHash = new Map<String,String>;
      this.eventTypeHash.set("Work Event","0");
      this.eventTypeHash.set("Social Event", "1");
      this.eventTypeHash.set("Task","2");
      this.eventTypeHash.set("","Misc");
  }

  submitEvent(){
      this.event.name = this.applyForm.value.name ?? '';
      this.event.description = this.applyForm.value.description ?? '';
      this.event.scheduledDate = this.applyForm.value.scheduledDate ?? '';
      this.event.scheduledTime = this.applyForm.value.scheduledTime ?? '';
      this.event.dueDate = this.applyForm.value.dueDate ?? '';
      this.event.attendees = this.applyForm.value.attendees ?? [];
      this.event.reminderScheduled = this.applyForm.value.reminderScheduled ?? false;

     this.eventService.submitEvent(this.event).subscribe(result => this.goToEventList());
  }

  goToEventList(){
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  selectEventType(value: string){
      this.event.eventType = this.eventTypeHash.get(value)!.toString();
  }

  selectUsers(value: string){
      this.selectedUsers.push(value);
      console.log(this.selectedUsers)
  }

  selectScheduleDate(value: string){
      this.event.scheduledDate = this.event.scheduledDate
  }

  scheduleReminder(value: boolean){
      this.reminderScheduled = this.event.reminderScheduled
  }

  selectScheduledTime(value: string | Date){
      let timeToString = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'hh:mm');
      this.scheduledTime = timeToString;
    console.log("here is time to string " + timeToString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using reactive forms and template forms on the same input?
You are using [(ngModel)]="date" and formControlName="scheduledTime" on the  igx. If you want to go template driven, then just use [(ngModel)] and then add (ngModelChange) instead of change.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular

Comment: I only used the template form method after my reactive forms method failed to work. I probably should have removed the template form code before submitting this question.