# Angular 2 : In ngModelChange function how to compare old and new values of ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to compare old and new values of ngmodel in ngModelchange function. I tried few solutions from stackoverflow but nothing is working in my case

This is my html code

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity" class="editInput" (ngModelChange)="rowchangcheck($event,item,i)" name="qty">
```

This is the function

```
 rowchangcheck(event, item, index) {
   console.log('oldvalue', item.quantity); //here value is getting changed
}
```

I have tried this but its not working
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544086/angular-2-ngmodelchange-old-value)

I want to get first value of ngModel before rowchange function and want to compare changed value with old one.How to do that please help

Comment: Have you looked at this [Angular 2 ngModelChange old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544086/angular-2-ngmodelchange-old-value)

Comment: @Lasse Did you read the question ? He puts a link to this question saying that it does not work for him.

Comment: Yes its not working

Comment: My bad - I had quit a few tabs open and took the wrong one..

Comment: I have tried almost all the answers of stackoverflow but nothing is working in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things like you, and I could only get it to work for the second input - for my first input the old value would always be undefined

The best I can come up with as of now is to add an OldQuantity:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IfWdvdy6JRsGvqsbDeN3?p=preview)

```
rowchangcheck(oldValue, event, item) {
  console.log('oldValue', item.oldQuantity);
  console.log('newValue', event);
  item.oldQuantity = event;
}
```